# Optimizing digit sum and product with GMP

Tags: c++, performance, comparative-review, gmp

I have a bottleneck in my program at the point where I calculate the digit sum and product of a number. I am using GMP because I have to work with numbers that follow \$1e8 < n < 1e80\$.

To calculate the sum/product of a number, I initially used strings, thinking the division/modulo method would result in an improvement later on.

However, when I later implemented this it turned out that this did not give me a performance improvement.

```
mpz_class num = 1120390317;
mpz_class sum = 0;
mpz_class pro = 1;

while(num != 0) {
    mpz_class rem = (num % 10);
    sum += rem;
    pro *= rem;
    num = num / 10;
}
```

Instead of:

```
mpz_class num = 1120390317;
mpz_class sum = 0;
mpz_class pro = 1;

const std::string strNum = num.get_str();
for (auto c : strNum) {
    int res = c - '0';
    sum += res;
    pro *= res;
}
```

In the actual program the values of `num` are actually in the before mentioned range. But they provide results about equal to [this test case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18f37c188e4ecc54).

The test case and the program shows me (with or without optimizations) using the first method is 3x as slow. How can I improve the modulo version to run faster than the string version? Or should I use the string version?  If so, can that be optimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to speed up your division.  First, note that because `rem` is declared within the `while` loop, it's both constructed and destroyed every loop iteration.  That's not really necessary, so you could instead declare it outside the loop and simply assign a new value within the loop each time.  Also by changing the line from `num = num / 10` to `num /= 10`, you avoid creating and destroying yet another temporary.  Applying both of those saves a little time, but it's still slower than the string method because you're essentially performing the division twice (once for `num % 10` and again for `num / 10`).

The key is to do only a single division per loop, but you'll have to resort to using the underlying C function since it's not exposed to the C++ interface. Fortunately, it's simple to do so:

```
unsigned long digit;
while(num != 0) {
    digit = mpz_tdiv_q_ui(num.get_mpz_t(), num.get_mpz_t(), 10);
    sum += digit;
    pro *= digit;
}
```

On my machine this is slightly faster than the string method, and probably uses a little less memory.

## Update:

Because the speed of that code relative to the string method varies based on what compiler optimizations are used, it's not necessarily always faster.  This version uses low-level GMP calls for more speed:

```
__mpz_struct *q = num.get_mpz_t();
while(*(q->_mp_d) != 0) {
    auto digit = mpn_divrem_1 (q->_mp_d, (mp_size_t) 0, 
            q->_mp_d, q->_mp_size, (mp_limb_t) 10);
    sum += digit;
    pro *= digit;
}
```

This makes a couple of assumptions that are important.  First, it assumes that `num > 0` and it dives deep into the internal structure of `__mpz_struct` so it will not be very durable to changes in GMP, should they decide to change the underlying representation of numbers.  However, with this code, I find that it's a bit faster on my machine than the string method, both with and without `-O3` optimizations.

Also, note that within your range of integers, the sum of digits will always fit within a `long int` which will save time, but could equally be applied to the string method.

Comment: Something like [this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/060f9f08df44ee71) It's still not as fast although a bit closer, am I missing something?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman It's all in how you compile it.  Without the `-O3` flag, on my machine, this version is faster, but with it, the string version is faster.  You may be able to use the [`mpn_tdiv_qr()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#Low_002dlevel-Functions) function to further optimize, but you'll also have to write more code since that's a low-level function.

Comment: Tested a bit with the flags but I don't seem to be able to get equal or better results. Do you think the low level functions will cover the gap (perhaps even faster timings)?

Comment: It is running at about the same speed on my machine now. Switching sum to `long` really helped out. Thanks!

Comment: For a very large number (e.g., a number with 10e8 *digits*), the string method is the fastest, as I have done [in this Code Challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37270/digit-sum-of-central-binomial-coefficients/37297#37297).